# How to select rows with specific string patterns in pandas?

Tags: python, string, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I know we can use `str.contains` method to select a partial string.

My column is like,

```
col1
V2648   
V9174.
V9071
V0021;+
V7615***
()()
random
words
```

I want to select all rows which contain a pattern with `V+ 4 digits number`. So we need to apply more than one condition on these strings.

My output will be like,

```
col1
V2648   
V9174.
V9071
V0021;+
V7615***
```

Comment: Are you familiar with regular expressions?

Comment: @Derek_6424246 Oh yes, I forgot that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
mask = df.col1.str.startswith('V') & df.col1.str.contains('\d+')
print(df[mask])
```

**Output**

```
       col1
0     V2648
1    V9174.
2     V9071
3   V0021;+
4  V7615***
```

The mask `df.col1.str.startswith('V')` checks everything that starts with `'V'` and `df.col1.str.contains('\d+')` checks everything that has `4` digits. If you want to match exactly a `V` followed by 4 digits use:

```
mask = df.col1.str.contains('^V\d+')
```

Comment: Hi @JiayuZhang Glad I could help, that one will match 5 digits, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

`str.match`

```
df[df.col1.str.match('[V](\d{4})')]
Out[135]: 
       col1
0     V2648
1    V9174.
2     V9071
3   V0021;+
4  V7615***
```